# How to use $this in closure in php

Tags: php, closures, this, anonymous-function

I have function like this:

```
class Service {
    function delete_user($username) {   
        ...
        $sessions = $this->config->sessions;
        $this->config->sessions = array_filter($sessions, function($session) use ($this){
            return $this->get_username($session->token) != $username;
        });
    }
}
```

but this don't work because you can't use `$this` inside `use`, is it possible to execute function which is member of class Service inside a callback? Or do I need to use for or foreach loop?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`$this` is always available in (non-static) closures since PHP 5.4, no need to `use` it.

```
class Service {
    function delete_user($username) {   
        ...
        $sessions = $this->config->sessions;
        $this->config->sessions = array_filter($sessions, function($session) {
            return $this->get_username($session->token) != $username;
        });
    }
}
```

See [PHP manual - Anonymous functions - Automatic binding of $this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it to something else:

```
$a = $this;
$this->config->sessions = array_filter($sessions, function($session) use ($a, $username){
   return $a->get_username($session->token) != $username;
});
```

You'll also need to pass `$username` through otherwise it'll always be true.

Comment: assign not cast